# PHP display elements of a json array

Tags: php, arrays, json, for-loop, each

i have a php problem. I want to 'echo' only special elements of this array, but i dont know how. Afterwards there is the code for echoing all strings in the form field. Thanks for your help.

```
$form_fields = json_decode($quitenicebooking_guest_details, TRUE); 

foreach ($form_fields as $key => $field) { 

echo htmlspecialchars($field['value']); 
}
```

Comment: since you haven't explained what makes an array entry "special", at best we can offer: `if (element is special) { echo it }`

Comment: Oh sorry. I want to select them by number, like this. `$field[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You could set an array of the field indexes (keys) you want to include. In the example below I've decided I want to echo only $field[1], $field[3] and $field[5]

```
$form_fields = json_decode($quitenicebooking_guest_details, TRUE); 

$specialKeys = array(1, 3, 5);

foreach ($form_fields as $key => $field) { 
    if (in_array($key, $specialKeys)) {
        echo htmlspecialchars($field['value']); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didnt worked. If I do var_dump($form_fields); then something like this comes out. It doesnt look like a normal array to me. Maybe this helps.

`array(9) { ["phone"]=> array(3) { ["label"]=> string(7) "Telefon" ["value"]=> string(9) "0123456678" ["type"]=> string(4) "text" } ["address_1"]`